# Parse names into first, middle, last when not everyone has a middle name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text

I have a df that looks a bit like this:

```
name                           id
John McNamara                  3498
Jane Adams, M.D.               6725
Nour Abd Almohsen Jr M.D.      0197
Alex Ambrose PhD               3287
Nancy Ann Brown, MPH, PhD      9127
Kathy W.                       4389
Jack Joshua Smith White        6756
```

I need to separate the name column into first name, middle name, last name, suffix, and title. Usually I would use something like `.str.split` but in this case not everyone has a middle name, suffix, or title. Additionally, some values have a comma separation and others don't. Is there any way to account for these differences?

Ideally I'd like my output to look like this:

```
first_name middle_name last_name    suffix title     id
John                   McNamara                      3498
Jane                   Adams               M.D.      6725
Nour       Abd         Almohsen     Jr     M.D.      0197
Alex                   Ambrose             PhD       3287
Nancy      Ann         Brown               MPH, PhD  9127
Jack       J           Smith White
```

edit: I'm aware this requires multiple steps, including likely stripping the punctuation. Some things I'm finding especially tricky:

- If I use something like `pd.concat([df['id'], df['name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)], axis=1)` a name like Jack Joshua Smith White ends up being split into multiple "middle name" columns where Smith is in the same column as all other people's last names. Is there a way to have the last string automatically go into the last column?
  I've tried to fix this by using something like df['last_name'].fillna(df['middle_name'], inplace=True) but that doesn't work because sometimes people have multiple "middle names" and I would need a way to select the latest middle name that's not `None`.

Comment: Can you make a list of all the suffix title that are contained within your dataframe or they can be arbitrary?

Comment: After you’ve checked and taken out the `title` field, you could use iterative unpacking: `first, *middle, last = parts_of_name`

Comment: @YacineMahdid in theory I could make a list of common suffixes, though it might not be comprehensive.

Comment: @NChauhan - what do you mean checked and taken out the title field? Like, strip the titles?

Comment: Once you have done `str.split` you get a list of all the ‘parts’. Your first action should be to look at the end of the list and pop the last item until it no longer classes as a ‘title’ (probably according to a list of possible titles). After that, you have a first and last name and maybe a middle. Iterable unpacking will allow you to separate all the middle names and get the first and last name.

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were able to get all the possible title in the dataframe, then parsing your names like this would be possible:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe with provided sample data
names = ['John McNamara','Nour Abd Almohsen Jr M.D.','Nancy Ann Brown, MPH, PhD','MPH']
med_id = ['3498', '6725', '0197', '3287', '9127','']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names, med_id)), columns =['name', 'id']) 
names = df['name'].to_list()


# List to fill up given the dataframe content
suffix = ['M.D.', 'PhD', 'MPH']
garbages = [',']

# iterate over all the name in your list
clean_names = []
first_name = []
middle_name = []
last_name = []
title = []

# Remove suffix and junk from the names
for name in names:
    to_remove = suffix + garbages
    clean_name = name
    for element in to_remove:
        clean_name = clean_name.replace(element, '')
    clean_names.append(clean_name)

# split the clean_names into first middle and last name
for (name,original_name) in zip(clean_names,names):
    data = name.split()

    # error checking for messed up entries
    if len(data) < 2:
        first_name.append("")
        middle_name.append("")
        last_name.append("")
        title.append("")
        print("Entry : " + original_name + " is malformed")
        continue

    # Add the right firstname lastname and middle name structure
    first_name.append(data[0])
    if len(data) == 2:
        middle_name.append("")
        last_name.append(data[1])
    else:
        middle_name.append(data[1])
        last_name.append(" ".join(data[2:]))

    # Add the right title
    title.append(' ,'.join([suf for suf in suffix if suf in original_name]))

df['first_name'] = first_name
df['middle_name'] = middle_name
df['last_name'] = last_name
df['title'] = title
df = df.drop(columns = ['name','id'])

print(df)
```

Here is the output with what you provided including a problematic entry:
[image]

However your dataset look highly irregular with respect to punctuation

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a pandas df. I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range`, when I assign `names = df['name'].to_list()`

Comment: is it possible that you have people with only a first name?

Comment: I don't believe so. There are some entries with only a last initial.

Comment: Could you produce an example?

Comment: Added one into the OP

Comment: @LMGagne I updated the code to work with data frame.
Could you be post the full error trace with this solution, it is working with the sample data you gave (see figure)

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-e51f644724df> in <module>
     25 
     26     # Add the right firstname lastname and middle name structure
---> 27     first_name.append(data[0])
     28     if len(data) == 2:
     29         middle_name.append("")

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204656/discussion-between-yacine-mahdid-and-lmgagne).